# How would you make a monad instance of this coroutine?

Tags: haskell, coroutine

I am rolling a `Coroutine` package for education purposes, here it is:

```
data Step a b r 
  = Stop
  | Yield b r      
  | Await (a -> r) 

instance Functor (Step a b) where
   fmap g s = case s of 
   Stop       -> Stop
   Yield b r  -> Yield b $ g r
   Await f    -> Await (g . f) 

data CoroutineT m a b = CoT { resume :: m (Step a b (CoroutineT m a b)) }

run_ :: Monad m => CoroutineT m a b -> [a] -> m [b]
run_ (CoT m) as = m >>= \step -> case step of
     Stop      -> return []
     Yield o r -> liftM (o:) $ run_ r as 
     Await k   -> case is of 
       []     -> return [] 
       (x:xs) -> run_ (k x) xs

instance Monad m => Functor (CoroutineT m a) where
  fmap g (CoT m) = CoT $ liftM ap m where 
    ap Stop        = Stop
    ap (Yield b r) = Yield (g b) (fmap g r)
    ap (Await k)   = Await $ (fmap g) . k


instance Monad m => Monad (CoroutineT m a) where
   return b      = CoT . return . Yield b $ return b    
   (CoT m) >>= g = CoT $ liftM go m where 
        go Stop        = Stop
        go (Yield b r) = undefined      -- * This line I am having trouble with
        go (Await k)   = Await $ (>>=g) . k
```

As you could see in the comments above, the only line I am having issue with the `Yield` case, I can see that

```
(>>=)     :: CoroutineT m a b -> (b -> CoroutineT m a c) -> CoroutineT m a c
(g b)     :: CoroutineT m a c
r         :: CoroutineT m a b
(r >>= g) :: CoroutineT m a c
```

But I am not sure of

1. How to put them together so it type checks
2. What the semantics of `bind` is in the case of `Yield`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Gabriel's suggestion, the alternate implementation.

```
data Step a b x r 
  = Done x 
  | Yield b r
  | Await (a -> r)
  | Fail

instance Functor (Step a b x) where
    fmap g s = case s of 
        Done x    -> Done x
        Yield b r -> Yield b (g r)
        Await k   -> Await $ g . k
        Fail      -> Fail


-- | note the monad type needs to parameterize over type of `x` in `Done x`
data CoroutineT a b m x = CoT { resume :: m (Step a b x (CoroutineT a b m x)) }

instance Monad m => Functor (CoroutineT a b m) where
  fmap g (CoT m) = CoT $ liftM ap m where 
    ap (Done x)    = Done $ g x
    ap (Yield b r) = Yield b (fmap g r) 
    ap (Await k)   = Await $ (fmap g) . k
    ap Fail        = Fail


instance Monad m => Monad (CoroutineT a b m) where
  return = CoT . return . Done
  (CoT m) >>= g = CoT $ m >>= \step -> case step of 
    Done x    -> resume $ g x
    Yield b r -> return . Yield b $ r >>= g
    Await k   -> return . Await $ (>>=g) . k   
    Fail      -> return Fail
```

Note the implementation of `return` makes more sense now as well.

Answer (score 4):

The base functor should be:

```
data Step a b r x 
  = Stop r
  | Yield b x      
  | Await (a -> x)
```

... and your coroutine type should be:

```
data CoroutineT m a b r = CoT { resume :: m (Step a b r (CoroutineT m a b r)) }
```

Until you make those two fixes it won't work.

Comment: Man sweet I was hoping you'd see this question. Could I ask you what r is in this case? And why is parametrizing Stop? Or is it just a place holder?

Comment: @chibro2 I highly recommend you read [issue 19 of The Monad Reader](http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/issue19.pdf), specifically the article on concurrency by Mario Blazevic.  That is the king of coroutine articles.  If you still do not understand why after reading that then just let me know and I will explain in greater detail.

Comment: Ahh I think in my mind `Stop` was `Fail`, but in this case `Stop` is the same as `Done` as seen in some implementations, and `Pure` in Pipes.Internal (right?). Ok less confused now haha

Comment: @chibro2 That's right.  `Stop` is behaving like `Pure`/`Done`.  You can still also have a `Stop` constructor in addition to `Pure`/`Done` and it will still work, too.